# Integration using the quad method python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to reproduce the error function using scipy, not using the erf  method.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad

def error_func(y):
    return 2/math.sqrt(np.pi)*quad(np.exp(-y**2), 1, np.inf, args=(y))[0]

g = [error_func(x) for x in np.arange(-1,1,0.2)]

print g
```

This code returns the following error message:

```
File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    g = [error_func(x) for x in np.arange(-1,1,0.2)]
  File "./test.py", line 7, in error_func
    return 2/math.sqrt(np.pi)*quad(np.exp(-y**2), 1, np.inf, args=(y))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 316, in quad
    points)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 383, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
quadpack.error: quad: first argument is not callable
```

If I understand correctly, the first argument of quad must be a function. I thing that I pass it right.
What is going wrong in my code?

Comment: The code you posted is visibly different from the code in the stack trace. The code in the stack trace has no `lambda y`. Make sure you're running the code you think you are.

Comment: I see you edited your post... but since your code still visibly doesn't match the stack trace, it's clear that you tried to just spot-fix the part I pointed out. Don't do that. Run code, get the error message, and then copy-paste both the exact code you ran and the exact error message into your question. Anything else hides bugs, introduces other bugs, and generally makes it much more difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quad` expects a function as its first argument. You give it `np.exp(-y**2)`, which is a number. Try replacing it with `lambda x: np.exp(-x**2)`. Also, read the `scipy.integrate.quad` docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that

```
np.exp(-y**2)
```

isn't a function. It's a number; specifically, it's the value of e^(-y^2). If you want to define a function that maps `y` to `np.exp(-y**2)`, the easiest way is with the `lambda` syntax:

```
lambda y: np.exp(-y**2)
```

You have other problems, though:

`(y)` isn't a tuple in `args=(y)`; it's just `y` in grouping parentheses. A 1-element tuple would be `(y,)`.

Also, you shouldn't be passing the `args` argument to `quad` anyway, since your function doesn't need any additional arguments beyond the one we're integrating over.

Finally, your integration bounds are wrong; you should be integrating from `0` to the argument of the error function:

```
def error_func(x):
    return 2 / math.sqrt(np.pi) * quad(lambda y: np.exp(-y**2), 0, x)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot!